# codeigniter autoload config file doesn't work in library

Tags: codeigniter, config, autoload

I created a customized config file called config2 and autoload it in autoload.php. In my model, i just use `$this->config->item('item_in_config2')`, it works well. However, in my paypal library, i tried to use the same thing like this:

```
$this->PROXY_HOST = $this->config->item['paypal_proxy_host'];
```

an error occur: undefined property $config. 
Then i tried to add  parent::__construct(); under library constructor, server error shows. Previously, i load the config2 manually and it worked well, but i really want to autoload it now. any ideas? thanks

Comment: I've run into this before. What are you using the second config file for? It's likely being loaded before something inside of it.

Comment: Hi Devin, i use the second config file for paypal, facebook etc. setup. how did you solve the problem? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to call the CI instance in the library:

paypal library constructor:

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$proxy_host = $CI->config->item('paypal_proxy_host');
```

Comment: Libraries do not share the same application scope as controllers or models. You need to retrieve the CI super object as stormdrain said. See [Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within Your Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html). If you want to use the `$this` syntax, you can do what models do, and use the `__get()` magic method to fetch the CI object. See `/system/core/Model.php`.